# saving timthumb output to the server using copy()

Tags: php, copy, save

Currently I am uploading files to the server. Once a file is uploaded, i get timthumb to to a resize and copy to another location.

```
copy(timthumb_image_address, new_server_address);
```

This has been working really well up until now. Timthumb works fine, but i can't get it to copy to the server properly. I makes invalid files now.

Folder which saves out the file is writeable. I can actually go in and download it. But i can't view the image itself upon download, or in the browser

There is no error message

Here are some dummy addresses I have been using

copy() part 1:

```
http://mywebsite.com/timthumb.php?src=/home/usernamehere/public_html/images/uploads/imagetocopy.jpg&w=32&h=32
```

copy() part 2:

```
/home/usernamehe/public_html/images/uploads/imagetocopy_v2.jpg
```

It made a file 533 bytes in size. No matter what, that is always the size i see in filezilla.

The only way i know its an invalid image is because nothing can open it. And picassa says its an invalid image. Despite having a .jpg extension by the way.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This needs more information. Do you get any messages? What does the new server address look like, can you show an example? What exactly do you mean by "invalid files" - what do they contain, how big are they? Does the source file exist? Is the target path writable?

Comment: you are right, sorry ill update it

Comment: Can you look into one of the 533 byte files with a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i solved it. I think it's because of apache password protection i put on. The file itself has a 401 error message

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Authorization Required</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: how can we solve this issue? I have the same problem. I have password , how can give the password?